# Expired Maltese residency permit and need to leave and return EU while waiting for the renewal

Tags: schengen, residency

I am currently waiting for the renewal of my expired residency permit from Malta. I have in hand an authorisation to stay in the country.

I need to travel back home to Canada before I receive the new card and then enter the EU again. Will I be entitled to use the 90-day visa free on my way back?

Thanks for your help :)